# Troubles with DateTime and PHP 5.2

Tags: php, php-5.2

I'm attempting to use the PHP DateTime class on a Solaris server with PHP 5.2.6, while testing on my local Windows box running PHP 5.3.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
try {
$dt = new DateTime('2009-10-08');
$dt->setDate(2009,10,8);
print_r($dt);
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

On the test server, things work flawlessly, this is what prints:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2009-10-08 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York )
```

On the server I need to use it on, however, this is what prints:

```
DateTime Object ( )
```

Removing the setDate makes no difference whatsoever.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks!

**Edit**

Modified the script:

```
try {
echo '|', date_default_timezone_get(), '|';
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo '|', date_default_timezone_get(), '|';
$dt = new DateTime('2009-10-08');
$dt->setDate(2009,10,8);
print_r($dt);
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

New output on the server:

```
|US/Eastern||America/New_York|DateTime Object ( )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, PHP 5.3 makes you set a default timezone in your php.ini, something which most php 5.2 installations completely ignore.  try setting it manually:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

Also, for the record, there are a few DateTime methods missing in 5.2 (get/set timestamp), you can find workarounds [here](http://blog.seanja.com/2010/03/php-datetime-is-missing-methods-in-5-2/)

Comment: I knew about the missing methods - I've just been avoiding them.

Unfortunately, setting the default timezone made no difference :(

Comment: just out of curiosity here, have you actually tested that the class isnt working? have you compared their actually functionality?  the empty dump doesn't necessarily mean its not working... :)

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure I understand or know how to do what you're describing.

Comment: I was being dense, the class actually was working, just as it's 5.2 it was incomplete.